# PHP - array filled with stdin integer input

Tags: php, arrays

Example :

```
$_fp = fopen("file.txt", "r");
/* STDIN = "4 7 6 24 1"; */ <== user input

$input[] = fgets($_fp);
print_r($input);
```

OUTPUT :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 4 7 6 24 1
)
```

Desired OUTPUT :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 7
    [2] => 6
    [3] => 24
    [4] => 1
)
```

Is there any method to remove spaces from integer input after entering each to an array?
In a way to avoid having the whole input as one single line.

i used `$input[] = explode(' ', trim(fgets($_fp)));` now when there is second line it only puts the first line of the STDIN i need to read all lines and put them into the input variable

`while($f = fgets(STDIN)){ echo "line: $f"; }` is great use here
it is fine for echoing all lines **but** cant assign each line to a variable or array yet.. not sure if i should `array_push()` since i need 2 lines as variables and rest as arrays..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use trim remove the "\n" of the line, the use explode to convert it to array.

[Live Demo](https://eval.in/689518)

```
$input = explode(' ', trim(fgets($_fp)));
```

if you has more lines, use below:

```
$input[] = explode(' ', trim(fgets($_fp)));
```

Comment: its works ! but is it efficient to access values through $input instead of  $input[0], since. print_r($input);
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
          [0] => 4
          [1] => 7
          [2] => 6
          [3] => 24
          [4] => 1
        )

)
for example $sum = array_sum($input); = // 0

Comment: I give you two version, if you just have one line, use the first.

Answer (score 1):

Even we can try preg_match_all with regx also give same result with all cases like what if you have double space or any text between the interger strings

```
$string = "4   7  6  24 1";
$string = "4 test df 7 6 24 1"; 
$string = "4 7 6 24 1";
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $string, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```